# Voice input in games beyond voip chat

Tags: cross-platform, input, voice

Is there any cross platform libraries available for handling input from a microphone?

I am thinking beyond voice chat to noise / voice recognition.

I am putting together a plan for a role playing game and in thinking of features I was thinking it would be nice if the player could be standing in a crowded place and yell and have the npc's react to that and look at the player for example.

As I plan to make this an open source project I want to make it as cross platform friendly as possible.

Comment: Depends, do you want it to actually respond to commands? Or just gauge yelling?

Comment: ideally respond to commands would be good, but I don't know if voice recognition is advanced enough yet to make that a viable option. If it only could understand you some of the time it would just make it frustrating.

Comment: Yeah, voice recognition is very difficult., And like Coderanger said below all of the open libraries are quite a bit behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Carnegie Mellon's Project Sphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/) it's an open source toolkit for speech recognition. I haven't used it, but it's certainly a place to start.

Comment: Basically all the open-source speech recognition systems are lightyears behind the commercial world unfortunately. The tech is all there, but they haven't had the same amount of time tweaking the pattern engines and they don't have access to the same size and quality of training data (that stuff is $$$$$).

Comment: For a game you don't need to rely on full-NLP. As long as you keep the available command list short and distinct even basic solutions can work. 

Here is Sphinx being used in a RTS-like demo example: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=owJS5XwXAEA

Answer (score 1):

[PortAudio](http://www.portaudio.com) should have a cross-platform input API, but I've never tried using it.